# Trying to get element and store them in array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html structure like this :

```
<tr>
    <td>NC</td>
    <td><%= @subscriptions.where("users.ranking = 'NC'").count %></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" class="checkbox-ranking" id="bite" data-size='small'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>40</td>
    <td><%= @subscriptions.where("users.ranking = '40'").count %></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" class="checkbox-ranking" data-size='small' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>30/5</td>
    <td><%= @subscriptions.where("users.ranking = '30/5'").count %></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" class="checkbox-ranking" data-size='small' ></td>
</tr>
```

I need to write a script that each time a checkbox is checked gets the innerhtml of the first `<td></td>` of each `<tr></tr>` where the checkbox is checked and returns it as an array.

Here's what I came up with :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checkbox-ranking').on('change', function() {
        var rankings = $('.checkbox-ranking:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children().first().html();
        }).get().join(',');
        alert(rankings);
    });
});
```

I must add that I installed the gem bootstrap-switch to have ON/OFF switch button and that is what my checkboxes are. I noticed that I switch on my button, it doesnt pass to `checked`in the html code, so I guess that's why my code isnt working: the script doesnt actually detects the on change event.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: try this simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/voueqhne/ check the console for values

Comment: did this fiddle help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now this works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checkbox-ranking').on('change', function() {
        var rankings = $('.checkbox-ranking:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first-child').html();
        }).get().join(',');
        alert(rankings);  
    });
});
```

and jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btrauybx/2/

Comment: `parent().parent().parent()` can be reduced to `parents().eq(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `closest()` and `first()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.checkbox-ranking').on('change', function(e) {
    var ranks = $('input.checkbox-ranking:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).closest('tr').children().first().text();
    }).get();
    alert(ranks.join(','));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>NC</td>
    <td>
      <%=@ subscriptions.where( "users.ranking = 'NC'").count %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" class="checkbox-ranking" id="bite" data-size='small'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>
      <%=@ subscriptions.where( "users.ranking = '40'").count %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" class="checkbox-ranking" data-size='small'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>30/5</td>
    <td>
      <%=@ subscriptions.where( "users.ranking = '30/5'").count %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" class="checkbox-ranking" data-size='small'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use `eq(0)` instead of `first()`.